# Can't connect to Internet via Ethernet wire

Tags: networking

I've instaled Ubuntu 16.04 yesterday, next to Windows7.
I am connected to router via Ethernet wire - it works fine on W7, but on Ubuntu I can't see any website, and can't ping anything.

WiFi connection works fine, but my room is too far from router. How can I fix this?

[image: screen of 'iconfig' result]

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
```

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

edit:

I've just observed that I can connect to Internet for about 45 seconds after pluging the Ethernet cable into my laptop. Ater 45 seconds there is no way to see any website again.

I also tried to update my drivers - didn't help.

Maybe this would be helpful:

```
piotr@Espadon:~$ sudo lspci | grep -i net
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 (rev c4)
```

Comment: Can you ping your router, at least?

Comment: It may be a DNS problem. Can you `ping 8.8.8.8`? (Google's primary DNS server)

Comment: Could you please [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/763096/edit) your question post the outputs for `route -n` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` when you're connected only through LAN?

Comment: Pinging both (router and 8.8.8.8) gives the same result "Destination Host Unreachable"

Comment: post the route -n command output as @AzkerM told you (and also cat /etc/resolv.conf)

Comment: Did you implement any ACL? I suspect that?verify that

Comment: It is indeed your DNS that is causing problem. Could you just edit the file with `nano /etc/resolv.conf` and replace the `127.0.1.1` with `8.8.8.8` and save it with **CTRL+O** and exit with **CTRL+W**. Afterwards, try to ping either google or 8.8.8.8 to see whether you're getting any reply. If it works, will advise further.

Comment: I didn't implement anything. It is just installed Ubuntu. But how can I verify that, to be completely sure?

Comment: @Piotrro there's nothing to do with ACL's? Please report back with my method.

Comment: you can check this accessing your router? I just wanted to be sure about it. You can follow him @AzkerM

Comment: Have you tried your wired connection after disabling the wifi ? Because your 2 adapters are in the same sub network

Comment: AzkerM, unfortunately your solution nothing changed. after changing it to 8.8.8.8 I couldn't ping google, and after reboot /etc/resolv.conf changed back to 127.0.1.1

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your network services. Try resetting them:
Open the terminal by pressing **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>** and then type in: `sudo service networking restart`.
After the command has run, restart your machine, and it will reconfigure the settings upon restart.

However, there are issues whereby Ubuntu writes *"Booting Up without full network config"*...a second restart will do the trick.

If this doesn't work, and the problem continues to persist afterwards, open the command line and type in this: 
`echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control`

This should resolve it, and ethernet is bound to work afterwards.

Comment: Service networking restart didn't help, and when I tried to do "echo on | ..." the tee told me that there is no directory like that

Answer (score -1):

Everything looks good, except one thing: You **DEFINITELY** need to fix your DNS.  replace that with

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

That way your router's DNS will be searched first, so if you want to use OpenDNS or something similar for site blocking you can.  After that, both of Google's Developer DNS servers will be searched.

Comment: His routing explain they are correct but not the DNS. Where do you see that the gateway is incorrect?

Comment: Arg.  You're right.  I misread the routing table.